# Java Spring & PDFBox merge PDFs and stream results back to client during the merge

Tags: java, spring, stream, pdfbox

I'm trying to create a Spring REST endpoint for merging multiple PDFs together which returns the resulting file in a stream. This is what I have right now:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/mergePdfs", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> mergePdfs2(@RequestPart @NotEmpty List<MultipartFile> pdfsToMerge,
                                                       @RequestParam(value = "correlationId", required = false) String correlationId,
                                                       @RequestParam(value = "resultFilename", defaultValue = "merged.pdf") String resultFilename) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("[ID: {}] Received a /v2/mergePdfs request", correlationId);

    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("[ID: {}] Beginning to merge {} PDFs into 1 PDF.", correlationId, pdfsToMerge.size());
            PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();

            for(MultipartFile pdfFile : pdfsToMerge) {
                pdfMerger.addSource(pdfFile.getInputStream());
            }

            pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(outputStream);
            pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
            LOGGER.info("[ID: {}] All PDFs merged.", correlationId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(MessageFormat.format("[ID: {0}] Couldn't merge all PDFs.", correlationId), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", resultFilename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now this works OK, it works for large enough files while not throwing Java Heap errors. The thing is it first merges everything and then it returns all the data back to client.

I would like to send the file back to the client in a stream which should be more memory-efficient (I presume) and is going to enable me to show progress on the client-side.

This is what I've tried:

- Use *mergeDocuments()* with main memory only setting

  - same result, occasional heap error
- Use *appendDocument()* and save to the outputStream after each document

  - heap error, I presume all data is stored in the destination PDDocument which becomes quite large

So what I need is to send results of the merge directly to the output stream as the merge is happening. Is it even possible to do with PDFBox alone?

Comment: No; PDFBox will have the whole document in memory at some time.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Well that's a bummer. I've seen it's possible to add pages from one PDF to another. Would it somehow be possible to say merge the document 50 pages at a time and then send the merged 50 pages down the stream?

Comment: Sure but you'll still have the merge the whole thing at some time. PDF isn't like HTML.